# Equal columns in Bootstrap's pagination when using a form input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this example pagination:

```
<nav aria-label="Pagination" class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="disabled">
      <span>Custom content here with <input value="input"></span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to have an input type inside one of the columns. However having anything but text there leads to columns not being of equal height:

[image: Pagination example]

What CSS I need to apply to have all columns equal? This example is available on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cd1sk0s2/1/) as well.

**Update**

With `.pagination a, .pagination span {height: 40px}` I got all columns equally high, however I cannot get the texts inside to appear in one line though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overide with a bit of css

**CSS**:

```
.pagination{display:inline-flex}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span{
     height:100%; display:flex; align-items:center
}
```

**Bootply**: https://www.bootply.com/YTnctq4PIg

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: This is great, and thank you! Just would like a small modification that accounts for the fact that the [pagination LESS code targets anchor *and span* elements](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/68b0d231a13201eb14acd3dc84e51543d16e5f7e/less/pagination.less#L13): a more complete version of that 2nd rule would be `.pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span{height:100%; display:flex; align-items:center}`. This is a great fix though, thanks again.

Comment: @YellowShark Thanks for your reply, changes are done for future reader.